# Better composition for react?

Tags: reactjs

Lets say I have a component **A** that renders 2 components **B** and **C**.

**B** and **C** renders cateogories and requires a `cat_id` as `props`.
They will call **apiB** and **apiC** using the `cat_id` respectively.

#### 1

Is it better to store `cat_id` in the parent (**A**) and pass `cat_id`as `props` to **B** and **C**? Note `cat_id` is dynamic and is stored as a state object in **A**.

When **A** call `setState` to update `cat_id`, **B** and **C** will call the apis in `componentDidUpdate`.

#### 2

Or is it better to call the apis in **A** instead, and pass off the results as props to **B** and **C** instead?

Reason I'm asking is because I'm using option 1 now. The child component has 4 renders on a single page load. I'm guessing having too much `setState` in the parent is bad.

I'd spent hours trying moving things around and changing condition in `componentDidUpdate` and `componentShouldUpdate` but it still seem slow.

Before I try option 2, would like to know if anyone already knows which is a better composition for React components.

Comment: What I feel its better to call apis of **b** and **c** in their respective components else there would be too much flow of that within componets. Also if you have such complex and large application you might wanna check out **flux** and **redux** so that the flow of data becomes easier and project is better structured.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like you've answered your own question a bit. Yes, in your case and assuming you're only using react right now, I would make the API calls in `A` and pass down the data as props to `B` and `C`.

You'd have other options for composition if you're using something like redux, where you'd fire off an action and let a reducer take care of the API calls for you, then update your store from there. But if you're just using react, option 2 is completely fine.

Comment: I agree. All the data fetching should be done in a container component. The children component are merely there to present the data in a friendly format and should not care about retrieving, but only receiving that data as props.